How to disable SSH password login in Sequoia
How do I disable SSH password login in Sequoia?
In previous MacOS versions you would edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
However, in Sequoia every line in that file commented out except:
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*
But the only file in that directory is: 100-macos.conf
Which contains nothing of interest.
So, where do I set PasswordAuthentication no, etc.?

How to configure OpenSSH has not changed.  What have you tried?

I hadn't tried anything. I was surprised by being able to remotely log on to my wife's account using password authentication; something I'm sure I had previously disabled. I was also surprised that the sshd_config file that I had previously edited had been replaced by a file with nothing but commented lines except for one include line. I decided that I needed to understand what was going on before I started editing files. Based on the answer provided by the famous Mr. Linc, I think I made the right decision.

Add a file to /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d with the directive(s) you want.

Thank you. Now that I know what I should have been searching for I've found plenty of material on what's going on. What concerns me a bit and something mentioned by others similarly situated is that the sshd_config file that I had previously edited seems to have been overlayed by a version containing nothing but commented-out lines and the one include line. So, apparently password login has been enabled without my knowledge. I guess I need to be more clever.

You can't count on Apple not to overwrite config files in /etc without warning when the OS is updated. They don't always do it, but they can.

Presumably they won't touch anything in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d so changes made via a file in that directory should stick. I hope.
